# How to get a data from a value with 2 or more items in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a select object in a row which has a value as an array of 2 items (coming from mongo database) as follows:

```
<td><select" name="lab" id="workedHr">
    <% siteexpense.sitelabours.forEach(function(lab){ %>
     <option value="['<%= lab.names %>', '<%= lab.workedHr %>']"><%= lab.names %> | <%= lab.workedHr %></option>
    <% }); %>                               
</select></td>
```

I'm just wondering how can i get the second item in the value in my function, is it gonna be something like this:

```
let cValue = document.getElementById("workedHr").value[1];
```

or if i wanna get this in may Node app.js like:

```
var a = req.body.lab[1]
```

Also, how can i get the value of each loop? at the moment i only can get the value of the first loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let cValue = document.getElementById("workedHr").value[1];
```

This way you will get the second character, not second value (in your case " ' ")
Get rid of the square brackets, split your value at comma and get the second element:

```
let cValue = document.getElementById("workedHr").value.split(',')[1];
```

Comment: another question is, because the select object is a loop, how can i get the value of each loop?